# WordPress update_user_meta does work with variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to update a user's meta data by calling the `update_user_meta()` function, but instead of having the value updated it will be set to *null* in the database.

Also, the value will be set to *null* even if it would have had same value that is already set for that `meta_key`.

What makes it bizarre is that the `update_user_meta()` works just fine if I am passing static text 'e.g. MyValue' to the function instead of the variable.

```
$phone = $_POST["PHONENUMBER"]; //has value 12345

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

echo 'Updating phone to value: ' . $phone . ' </br>';
//Output is "Updating phone to value: 12345"

//This will set lc-phone value to NULL even if the old value would have been 12345. 
update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'lc-phone', $phone);

//this will update the lc-phone value to 12345
update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'lc-phone', '12345');
```

I also added the following debug code in the `update_metadata()` function in `meta.php`.

```
echo var_dump($meta_value) . '</br>';
```

But the output in both cases is: string(5) "12345"

Can anyone tell what is the difference on those calls variable vs. static text?

Comment: Do you want to update the user_meta only if it is not already set/exist?

Comment: user_meta should be updated if it has been changed but for my understanding update_user_meta function does that check. And does not really matter is it would be the same value anyway. 

But is there something different of variables in php because I have tried with 
$phone = $_POST["PHONENUMBER"];
and
$phone = '12345';

And in both cases gettype ($phone) shows it is a string and in my test both cases the value is same but still only the later one works with update function.

Answer (score 0):

You Should Check $_POST value before the update in the database.

```
if( isset($_POST['phonenumber']) and is_user_logged_in() ) {

$user_id = get_current_user_id();

//Get phone numer
$phone = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['phonenumber'] );

//Update user meta
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'lc-phone', $phone);
}
```

validation form is very important always :)
if $_POST = null ,This means $_POST not set.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [`wp_get_current_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/), why not make use of `global $current_user;`?

As such:

```
global $current_user;

$phone = $_POST["PHONENUMBER"]; //has value 12345

//$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
// and the rest of your code
```

You may want to sanitise inputs (safety precaution; obviously not related to the challenge faced) as well as checking to ensure the current user has logged (only then you should perform the operation as `$current_user` would have had no records for a non active user).

Comment: Good points. I had just simplified my example bit. Code runs in member area valid login and rights are checked on page level. Sanitize check is good but not the cause of the issue as the field $phone is proved to have a value (just numbers) in my test and that is even passed correctly in update_user_meta.